# netsutie:How to reload current page without losing form data in netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

There is a sales order record in edit mode.I use `window.location.reload()` to refresh current page in cilent script after edit some fields value.Then all the data are restored.If I want to reload current page without losing any form data,how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can get values which are changed using field change function. Then before reloading function load the record and set the values which are changed and then save the record object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we have to understand the functionality and flow of the script first.

Before submitting the record, the data is at the client side ONLY. And to persist the data, you need to save/commit the data in to the Netsuite database.

As soon as the refresh button is hit, it fetches the data from the Netsuite database (which makes sense) and populate the data on to the page.

I hope it clears.

All the best.